# Synchronization problem AX 2012 R2 - "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I had a problem with synchronazing the database in AX 2012, the error was caused by one column lets name it column 'X'. I deleted column X from SQL, and run synchronization again in AX now sync finish successfully but if i try to open that table in table browser from AX AOT i have an error.

> Cannot select a record in LedgerParameters".The SQL database has
> issued an error.
>  Invalid column name "X".

I tried full compile,incremental CIL, again sync, restart the AOS. But it doesn't help, i still see that field in AOT and still have problems with the table.

Any way to sync it on right way, to have exact situation in AOT like in the SQL server object.

Comment: I use microsoft sql server

Comment: If this is a production issue, there's a different way to handle it. If it's not, then delete it from the AOT and re-add it. If column `X` is a mandatory field, then you need to initialize it in `LedgerParameters.initValue()`. You can just right click on the table and synchronize the single table instead of a full sync while you sort the issue.